# A hashing algorithm for comparing different hashes of same input by each other

Tags: hash, cryptography, bcrypt, password-hash

I'm looking for a hash algorithm that generates many hashes for each input like bcrypt but unlike that in comparing phase it should can compare one of the many hashes that can generates for an input by another one hash of the input.

For example:

```
hash_a = hash(the_input)

hash_b = hash(the_input)

(hash_a != hash_b)=> false //are not same 

compare(hash_a,hash_b) => true //verified

compare(hash_a,any_thing_else) => false //invalid
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're asking for here. Can you provide more context? Why do you think you need this functionality?

Comment: By the way, you may want to have another look at the double negative in `(hash_a != hash_b)=> false //are not same`....

Comment: some thing like bcrypt; it generates multiple hash output for one input and can verify generates hashes by the original input but in need something should can compare generated hashed by each other not only by the original. something like sha + bcrypt

Comment: This sounds like an X -> Y problem... why do you think you need this?  What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark It is for distributed user account manager that each user save another user info encrypted

Comment: That doesn't really answer either of my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use salts with hashing by specific algorithms that allow salts for hashing like Argon2 password hashing algorithm. can find more algorithms by searching for “salted password hashing algorithm”.